# popup once every 5 minute

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup

i have a bootstrap modal popup with following code that runs every time page loads. 
I need the script run once for each session with cookie and cookie will expire after 5 minutes. can you please help?

here's the code:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check google before asking since this has quite a few duplicate answers

Comment: I made it clear and changed the question.. thank you.

Comment: What does the cookie do? "run with cookie" does not explain much

Comment: anyone who knows the answer would understand what I meant. thank you.

Comment: Weird comment. I know how to set a cookie. Why would I need to to pop a dialogue?

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval(showModal, 300000);

function showModal()
{
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```